# integrating c++ static library built with /MD runtime library type within a project with /MT libraries on windows

Tags: c++, windows, static-libraries

I am currently working on a project that uses `/MT` the multithread, static version of the run-time libraries , and all of its dependencies are static .lib libraries provided with this option.

now I have to integrate a new library that is a static library .lib file built with `/MD` option and unfortunately I only have access to the header files and the .lib static library which is build with `/MD` option. therefore the linker forbids me of linking to it.

Is there any trick that I could use to force the linker to accept it, or somehow repack or recompile the object files inside the library (which I don't have access to the source code) Compatible with the `/MT` option?

Comment: My advice is to compile your code with the same runtime as the library if you can't recompile the library.

Comment: @drescherjm, yes this is a good idea , but unfortunately i don't have access to the source code of all of the libraries that im using in the project

Comment: Have a read of [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Even if there is trick, it's not worth it. The only quick solution I can think of is to use that library and create exe which you could call.